# How print barcode without digits with ZPL lang

Tags: zpl

How print code128 barcode without digit, just image of barcode?
my example with digits:

```
^FO20,20
^BCN,50,Y,N
^FD1234567890^FS
```

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I couldn't find it in the manual so I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the **ZPL II Programming Guide**

`^BC` is for printing Code 128 Bar Codes

Format: `^BCo,h,f,g,e,m`

```
o = orientation
h = height
f = interpretation line
g = interpretation line above code
e = UCC check digit
m = mode
```

You are setting f  to `Y`, change that to `N`.

```
^BCN,50,N,N
```